# Difference between "durchsetzen" and "umsetzen"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

How do I differentiate between *umsetzen* and *durchsetzen* in the sense of completing a job off executing it?

Could you give some examples to help me get a better understanding of these two words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- umsetzen: doing something that has been described by someone or a paper or another source, thus following some form of guideline or procedure or request.
- durchsetzen: enforce that something is done. It is more powerful than "umsetzen" but has also (sometimes) a negative co-notation.

Comment: Abhängig vom Kontext hat "umsetzen" ebenso negative Konnotationen. `Die Regierung hat die aufgeweichten Grenzwerte für Schadstoffe flächendeckend umgesetzt.` - abhängig natürlich davon, ob man selbst zur Regierung gehört oder zu den Begünstigten. Diese Idee mit den Konnotationen passt auf alles und jedes - für viele hat Schokolade negative Konnotationen - das ist nicht der Erwähnung wert, sondern absolut irrelevant.

Comment: An sich hat "umsetzen" keine negativen Konnotationen. Wenn allerdings was Negatives umgesetzt wird, kann das natürlich negativ wirken.

Answer (score 1):

There are considerable differences.

*Umsetzen* means *to realize* (or *to realise* :-) and is rather neutral, while *durchsetzen* means *to enforce* or *to push through*, which implies force and often has negative connotations.

Answer (score 0):

Umsetzen: Eine Anforderung an ein Programm umsetzen. Die Anforderung programmieren, umsetzen. Oder allgemeiner, eine Arbeitsanweisung ausführen, umsetzen.

Durchsetzen: Ein Kollege und du, ihr habt für das gleiche Problem unterschiedliche Lösungen. Deine ist besser und wird umgesetzt. Du hast dich mit deiner Idee durchgesetzt/gegenüber seiner Idee durchgesetzt.

Answer (score 0):

- Umsetzen: Einen Plan in die Tat umsetzen, verwirklichen.
- Durchsetzen: Etwas gegen Widerstände durchsetzen, verwirklichen. Sich durchsetzen, die eigenen Ziele und Pläne verwirklichen.

Man kann sich nicht selbst umsetzen, außer im Kino, wenn man schlecht sieht - dann setzt man sich im wahren Sinne des Wortes um.

Answer (score 0):

Umsetzen is more like in a transmition to change the ratio.
while durchsetzen is more to force through

Comment: What do transmission to change the ratio and completing a job have in common?